# Extra big table causes a Allowed memory size of x bytes exhausted error

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have an Entity that is joined to a massive table: 200.000 rows.

The problem I face is that when I bind an entity object into a form, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 85 bytes) in
>   /../public_html/application/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php
>   on line 296

Annotation is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="This\Entity\Table", mappedBy="id")
 **/
private $sometable;
```

What I believe is happening is that Doctrine is attempting to load the table into memory and this is what kills the process.

When I comment out the table, everything works as expected.

I read up about lazy loading and tried to add this to the annotations:

```
 fetch="EXTRA_LAZY"
```

However it didn't solved the problem.

I load the entity via a service:

```
$object = $this->someRepository->find($id);
// And bind..
$this->form->bind($object);
```

What is the correct way to handle something like this?

Comment: Without knowing about the size of data in related tables, how queried, how associated (uni-bi/direct) and current configuration of the DoctrineORMModule its hard to say the correct reason of memory exhaustion. For development purposes, `128M` of memory is pretty low to work on large, mature and complex libraries such as doctrine. I strongly recommend to increase `memory_limit` in `php.ini` to `256M` or higher. Can you improve the question a little more?. For example is `xdebug` enabled on your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but 200k table is not massive, in fact, no where close to it, MySql should return such a query in subsecond times. I therefore think that the problem lies in your mapping and indexes or lack of. You should also look at Database caching but sort out the indexes and query first.

Update your question with more code.